ansible can't restart/reload chrooted stunnel
I created chrooted configuration for stunnel. When I run locally
stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf
stunnel started fine and run 6 processes.
When I send the HUP signal locally, stunnel reloaded configuration successfully.
kill -SIGHUP `cat /usr/local/stunnel/stunnel.pid`

When I start it via ansible like this
  - name: Start stunnel
    command: stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf

stunnel started, but there are only 1 process and its services don't work.
When I send the HUP signal from ansible, stunnel not works.
  - name: Check stunnel is running
    stat:
      path: /usr/local/stunnel/stunnel.pid
    register: stunnel

  - name: get pid
    command: cat '/usr/local/stunnel/stunnel.pid'
    register: pid
    when: stunnel.stat.exists

  - name: Reload stunnel configuration.
    command: kill -SIGHUP {{ pid.stdout }}
    when: stunnel.stat.exists

